# Merge selected group keys in KDB (Q) group by query

Tags: kdb

I have a query that essentially does counting by group key in KDB, in which I want to treat some of the groups as one for the purpose of this query. A simplified description of what I'm trying to do would be to count orders by customer in a month, where I have a couple of customers in the database that are actually subsidiaries of another customer, and I want to combine the counts of the subsidiaries with their parent organisation. The real scenario us much more complicated than that and without getting into unnecessary detail, suffice to say that I can't just group by customer and manipulate the results to merge counts after the query is executed - I need the "by" clause of my query to do the merging directly.

In SQL, I would do something like this:

```
select customer_id, count(*) as order_count
from orders
order by select case when customer_id = 1 then 2 when customer_id = 3 then 4 else customer_id end
```

In the above example, customer 1 is a subsidiary of customer 2, customer 3 is a subsidiary of customer 4 and every other customer is treated normally

Let's say the equivalent code in Q (without the manipulation of group keys) is:

```
select order_count:count i by customer_id from orders
```

How would I put in the equivalent `select case` statement to manipulate the group key? I tried this, but got a `rank` error:

```
select order_count:count i by $[customer_id=1;2;customer_id=3;4;customer_id] from orders
```

I'm terrible at Q so I'm probably making a very simple mistake. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach might be to have a dictionary of subsidiaries and use a lookup/re-map in your by clause:

```
q)dict:1 3!2 4
q)show t:([] order:1+til 10;customer:1+10?6)
order customer
--------------
1     1
2     1
3     6
4     2
5     3
6     4
7     5
8     5
9     3
10    5

q)select order_count:count i by customer^dict[customer] from t
customer| order_count
--------| -----------
2       | 3
4       | 3
5       | 3
6       | 1
```

You will lose some information about who actually owns the orders though, you'll only know at the parent level

Comment: If that works, it's much more elegant than inlining the clause as I had in mind :) Thanks very much - let me try applying it to my real scenario now and see if it holds, but it looks completely logical to me

Comment: Yep, that did exactly what I wanted, thanks very much!